# Eclipse Plugin project: manage external files

Tags: windows, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for Eclipse (4.2 on windows) that uses a bunch of external files (batch scripts, xml files, ecc).
I'm asking if there is a good method to manage those files inside the project in order to:

- keep all the plugin resources inside the project for version control in SVN
- possibly have an automated plugin installation (including those files outside the plugin jar)

Edit: Can an additional "Feature Project" be a solution?
Instead of having a project I would manage two: one for the plugin and one for the "feature" that references the plugin and gathers the non-plugin data.

In that case, I see that eclipse "Features" have an "installation" section (in "feature.xml"). How could I specify for each "non-plugin" file the install path location?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using nested projects for this.

Create a parent project that will contain everything. For each sub-project, deactivate the default location when you create it and select the parent project's root folder instead.

Here is an example: http://git.eclipse.org/c/tmf/org.eclipse.xtext.git/tree/

It doesn't have a `.project` file in the root but having one doesn't hurt.

Just remember to import the sub-projects before you start working on them. Otherwise, you and Eclipse might get confused.